# Storing subprocess.call data to a varaible

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi am writing a code to get the curl response of a list of website

Here is my attempt

```
import requests
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
import subprocess
f = open("subdomains.txt")
line =f.readlines()
i=0;
while(i<100):
    x=(line[i]).rstrip("\n")
    def convert(url):
        if url.startswith('http://www.'):
            return 'http://' + url[len('http://www.'):]
        if url.startswith('www.'):
            return 'http://' + url[len('www.'):]
        if not url.startswith('http://'):
            return 'http://' + url
        return url
    print convert(x)
    res = subprocess.call("curl -I " +convert(x),shell=True)
    i=i+1
    print "______________________"
    w=open("output.txt".'a')
    w.write(res)
    w.close
```

If I remove the last 3 lines . The code works efficiently but the part to append the data to the output file fails. Anyone can suggest me how to make the subprocess.call data append into the output file ? The error what I get get after running my code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shashank01.py", line 24, in <module>
    w.write(res)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

Comment: You probably want `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: With that the ouput does get saved but if a website does not resolve then the code breaks . I want to code to continue . Any suggestions ?

Comment: `proc = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE); out = proc.communicate()[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open("output.txt",'a')
subprocess.call("curl -I " +convert(x),shell=True,stdout=f)
```